# Listening a port in c# (not a TCP port)

Tags: c#, sockets, voip, sip

My situation: I have an xspeech for voip, when there is an action about phone, the messages(packets) are sent to the xspeech interface. And from this interface the logs of these action are sent to specific IP address which is my IP address. And also these logs are sent from a specific port.

I am trying to develop an application that reads these logs(not a file). I tried TCPListener and TCPClient, they worked but not in my situation. I thought these logs are not sent from TCP port. This is the problem.

Comment: You may be receiving the SIP messages in a Datagram (UDP) instead of a STREAM (TCP) ... Try it.

Comment: please elaborate... what port ? any link to a spec or description of the protocol ?

Comment: it assumes that the logs are sent to a specific IP address and a specific port. I am in the same network with the xspeech. I've gave my ip address for server address and I am using port 514.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post I suspect it is using UDP... this would mean that you need to use [UDPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class to receive and process...

Depending on whether they offer a TAPI provider you can use:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/devangpro.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CShart_TAPI_3x.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734214.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It may be necessary to build a SIP proxy (this would be able to generate for example "Pickup event"):

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SIP_stack_with_SIP_proxy.aspx
- http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/
- http://www.independentsoft.de/sip/index.html
- http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx
- http://www.voiceelements.com/Products/VEToolkit.aspx

**EDIT - as per comments other possibilities:**

If what you try to catch is sent as syslog message then see http://michael.chanceyjr.com/useful-code/syslogd-class-for-sending-and-receiving-syslogd-events/ .

Another possibility is SNMP - for this see http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to try this.

Comment: @user1039290 it could be syslog OR SNMP too... I added some links for those too...

Comment: yes, it worked, i wrote an udp listener class and it catches all the messages thank you very much.

Comment: @user1039290 glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 1):

SIP uses UDP per default.

It's not as simple as being able to take packets from one endpoint, log them and then send them to the real destination. You'll break things like NAT handling if you do so.

You need to act as a full SIP proxy (stateful) or as a B2BUA.

The easier way is to download an existing sip-proxy and just make it log to a file and read that file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to try this.

Comment: I might have missunderstood you. Do `xspeech` have a dedicated logging interface? If so, it's not SIP but maybe messages for a `syslog` server.

Comment: yes there is a logging interface. In its documentation, the information in the interface are filled through SIP. When I picked up the phone, it writes "Picked Up" in the interface. When I dialed, the number that I've dialed is shown, etc. And it assumes it sends the logs to my IP Address from a specific port. I tried to upload the screenshot but because I'm new I couldn't.

Comment: Pickup is not an event which can be generated through sip (I don't think that presence subscription have a off hook event either). The logging interface is probably independent of SIP. you can use `netstat -b -a` from a command window to see all connections on your computer (if you are running the administration interface on it). However, I would try to  find a logging specification instead of trying to reverse engineer the protocol.

Comment: first of all, thank you for replies.
I tried to get packets with UDPClient class and it looks fine for now. in a long term, i try to find a logging specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're recieving the information on at your IP address then I too would have thought that TCP/IP was being used. Have you checked that your firewall isn't blovking the port in question.
I would suggest that you have another look at what protocol is being used (it may be UDP) and use the `Socket` class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When I sent a message from the client which I wrote, TCPListener catchs it. But same TCPListener couldn't catch the logs. I send messages from the same port.